# Multi Mapping in Dapper. Receiving the error in SpiltOn

Tags: dapper, multimap

***Can You explain the Split on function in the multimap ***

I am Trying to  get the data from the Database using Dapper ORM. I have received the following error 
***System.ArgumentException : When using the multi-mapping APIs ensure you set the splitOn param if you have keys other than Id
Parameter name: splitOn***

```
 public abstract class Domain
    {
       public Guid Id { get; set; }
    }


public abstract class ItemBase : Domain
  {
     private IList<Image> images = new List<Image>();
     public Guid? ParentId { get; set; }
     public string Name { get; set; }
     public IList<Image> Images { get { return images; } }
  }

 public class Meal : ItemBase
   {

   }

public class Item : ItemBase
  {
     private IList<Meal> meals = new List<Meal>();
     public IList<Meal> Meals { get { return meals; } };
  }


public class Image : Domain
  {
      public byte Img { get; set; }
       public string Description { get; set; }
   }



 public  class MealImageLink : Domain
 {
     public Guid ItemId { get; set; }
     public Guid ImageId { get; set; }
 }
```

/* search  function to take dat from the table */

```
private List<Meal> SearchMeals(Guid id)
 {
   var query = @"SELECT meal.[Name],meal.[Description],meal.

   [Price],mealImage.[Image] as Img    
                                  FROM      [MealItems] as meal  
                                  LEFT JOIN   [MealImageLink] mealImageLink 

  on meal.Id= mealImageLink.MealItemId
                                  LEFT JOIN   [Images] mealImage on  

   mealImageLink.ImageId=mealImage.Id
                                  WHERE  meal.[ParentId]=@Id";

List<Meal> meals = ( _connection.Query<Meal, MealImageLink, Image, Meal>
                                       (query, (meal, mealLink, mealImage) =>
                                       {
                                           meal.Images.Add(mealImage);
                                           return meal;
                                       }, new { @Id = id })).ToList();
return meals;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The multi-map feature is really more intended for scenarios like:

```
select foo.Id, foo.whatever, ...,
       bar.Id, bar.something, ...,
       blap.Id, blap.yada, ...
from foo ...
inner join bar ...
left outer join blap ...
```

or the lazier but not uncommon:

```
select foo.*, bar.*, blap.*
from ...
inner join bar ...
left outer join blap ...
```

But in both of these cases, there is a clear and obvious way to split the horizontal range into partitions; basically, whenever you see a column called `Id`, it is the next block. The name `Id` is configurable for convenience, and can be a delimited list of columns for scenarios where each table has a different primary key name (so `User` might have `UserId`, etc).

Your scenario seems quite different to this. It looks like you're currently only selecting 4 columns with no particular way of splitting them apart. I would suggest that *in this case*, it is easier to populate your model via a different API - in particular, the `dynamic` API:

```
var meals = new List<Meal>();
foreach(var row in _connection.Query(sql, new { @Id = id }))
{
    string name = row.Name, description = row.Description;
    decimal price = row.Price;
    // etc

    Meal meal = // TODO: build a new Meal object from those pieces
    meals.Add(meal);
}
```

The `dynamic` API is accessed simply by not specifying any `<...>`. With that done, columns are accessed by name, with their types implied *by what they are being assigned to* - hence things like:

```
decimal price = row.Price;
```

Note: if you want to consume the `row` data "inline", then just cast *as soon as possible*, i.e.

```
// bad: forces everything to use dynamic for too long
new Meal(row.Name, row.Description, row.Price);

// good: types are nailed down immediately
new Meal((string)row.Name, (string)row.Description, (decimal)row.Price);
```

Does that help?

Tl;dr: I just don't think multi-mapping is relevant to your query.

---

Edit: here's my best guess at what you intend to do - it simply isn't a good fit for multi-map:

```
var meals = new List<Meal>();
foreach (var row in _connection.Query(query, new { @Id = id })) {
    meals.Add(new Meal {
        Name = (string)row.Name,
        Images = {
            new Image {
                Description = (string)row.Description,
                Img = (byte)row.Img
            }
        }
    });
}
return meals;
```

Comment: Can you explain elaborately about the Dynamic API   below code                                        ***` var meals = new List<Meal>();
               foreach(var row in _connection.Query(sql, new { @Id = id }))
                  {
                     string name = row.Name, description = row.Description;
    decimal price = row.Price;
              // etc

                         Meal meal = // TODO: build a new Meal object from those   pieces
             meals.Add(meal);
          } `***

Comment: As per the understanding of the spliton function  ,I have re arranged the code 
 as ***`List<Meal> meals = ( _connection.Query<Meal, MealImageLink, Image, Meal>
                                       (query, (meal, mealLink, mealImage) =>
                                       {
                                           meal.Images.Add(mealImage);
                                           return meal;
                                       }, new { @Id = id },splitOn: "Name")).ToList();`***, I am Receiving the same error

Comment: "I have re arranged the code as..." - indeed; you're telling it to split horizontal partitions by the column called `Name`. The only column called  `Name` happens *in the first column*. There would be absolutely no way of getting any data for any of the other partitions, ... so ... the message is correctly identifying that something is very wrong.

Comment: @chaaru "Can you explain elaborately..."; you have 4 columns, which can be extracted as per the code I have shown. Once you have those 4 values, a `Meal` can presumably be constructed (you did choose those 4 values, etc). I'm not sure what you want me to add there...

Comment: :"Can you explain elaborately." Still I have a doubt where i have to write the execution command inside ***`foreach(var row in _connection.Query(sql, new { @Id = id }))`*** this  or any where else.Pleases give the full code . Am new to this Dapper and C#

Comment: @chaaru I've added my best guess as to what you intend to do. The problem here is that the shape of your data isn't a direct fit to **either** regular `Query<T>` or multi-mapping (`Query<,,,>`). But in that scenario, we can still use dapper to do *most* of the work, and just shape the data ourselves.